# How do i look at the optimizations the compiler has made

Tags: go

Is there a built in way to look at the optimizations the go compiler has made or the code generated by the go compiler, for example how do I know if a function was made inline?

Comment: Read the second paragraph from [this link](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/10/07/notes-on-exploring-the-compiler-flags-in-the-go-compiler-suite). Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: @JohnSPerayil I actually found when I need with `go tool compile`, thanks a lot for the insight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the generated code:

```
go tool objdump myprogram.exe

go tool objdump -s "\.String" myprogram.exe
```

The latter command only disassembles all `String` functions.